# Placement new, objects placed over I/O registers and zeroed memory

Tags: c++, embedded, reinterpret-cast, placement-new, ioports

I've been experimenting with placement new to "map" classes on top of I/O space to save some memory:

```
hardware::ioport *port = new(0xWHATEVER) hardware::ioport();
```

which works nicely, but zeros out the bytes at 0xWHATEVER. The "alternative" solution

```
hardware::ioport *port = reinterpret_cast<hardware::ioport *>(0xWHATEVER);
```

works as well, but does not call the default constructor I implemented.

Is there any way to call the constructor, but do not zero-out the memory beforehand in C++?

Comment: How is `hardware::ioport` defined?

Comment: Also, this question is a bit confused: You want to create an object, but also not modify any memory?!

Comment: There is a great example shown by Stephen Dewhurst at an Embedded East conference several or ten or more years ago on using templates to map memory mapped I/O registers to classes and objects, for both read-only and read/write bit values. I wish I could find an Internet citation. Optimized code was incredibly compact. The reading from a register resulted in a 'load indirect via a constant' using standard  C++ objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  hardware::ioport *port = new(0xWHATEVER) hardware::ioport();
```

The () parentheses after ioport() invokes automatic zero-initialization on pod members of the ioport class.  Clearly you don't like this feature, just remove them.  Fix:

```
  hardware::ioport *port = new(0xWHATEVER) hardware::ioport;
```

Comment: I think that this is misleading. If there is a user-declared constructor then there is no difference between the two initializations. In the either case there is no automatic initialization of pod members unless there is no user-declared default constructor. Further more, there is no guarantee that with or without a user-declared constructor that the second version _doesn't_ write anything (zeros or a guard pattern) to the space where the object is being constructed before the actual initiazation of any bases and members of the class, it's a valid implementation choice.

Comment: Well, that's correct. I just figured that my constructor in question was commented out, so the question was wrong. With existing constructor there seem to be no difference.